# local assets(css/js) not found when using apache virtual host

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, virtualhost

I've added  `127.0.0.1 my.pro`  to my hosts file

and add below code to `httpd-vhosts`

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ci4/public"
    ServerName my.pro
    ErrorLog "logs/myproject-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/myproject-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

the problem is i can't reffer to my assetes.
 **assetes and project index page are in defferent directories**.

```
-ci4
--public
---index.php
--assets
---css
```

`C:/xampp/htdocs/ci4/public` is project root and i locate assetes in `C:/xampp/htdocs/ci4/assetes` .

when I try to load a CSS file with this resource `http://my.pro/assets/css/style.css` it shows 404 error.
I know apache tries to load file from `C:/xampp/htdocs/ci4/public/assets/css/style.css` which doesn't exist.

but I have no idea how to fix it!

Comment: Why you are putting assets folder outside the `public` folder? they are supposed to be inside that folder, remember you configured apache to see `public` as your webroot folder.

Comment: @SaydFuad is it good practice to put assets in public folder? what about user uploaded files? and anyway, is it possible in apache vhost?

Comment: Try to keep the assets folder inside the public and see the result. all user writeable folders can stay in a public folder and you can protect them from direct access too

Comment: it works fine when I put assets in the public folder. thanks.